# image uploads in ckfinder but not showing in ckeditor

Tags: php, html, upload, ckeditor, ckfinder

As i upload using ckfinder the file/image uploads in the defined folder,
but it return a url to ckeditor, using the url the image is not loading in ckeditor, i dont know why, am working in the localhost,

my config is as follows-

```
baseUrl = "/var/www/html/WC/joseph/plugins/ckfinder/userfiles/"
```

the ckfinder returns the same url to ckeditor, but it doesnt loads image with http://localhost the image loads,

but i cant able to change the config as locahost, when i change it then the upload doesn't works, anyone plzz help me

Comment: Can you put full configuration? It looks like you need to change `baseUrl` to `root`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `baseUrl` option, like you can guess from the name, is used to define a base URL. It looks like you have passed to it a path of the physical directory on your server, which is incorrect. Instead, you should put  there the URL which points to `userfiles` folder location.

Basing on directory path from your question let's assume that your website is available under `https://example.com` domain, and the root folder for this domain is served from `/var/www/html/WC/` directory. In this case you should define `baseUrl` as follows:

```
baseUrl = "https://example.com/joseph/plugins/ckfinder/userfiles/"
```

CKFinder will know how to build URL-s for files which should resolve the issue.